# How to load specific page for subdomain url, using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, subdomain

How can I let my server load (*invisibly!*) somepage.htm, when an url is given with a subdomain in front of it, using only Apache's .htaccess ?

So that when user types `subdomain.website.org` then server loads  `website.org/somepage.htm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as both **subdomain.website.org** and **website.org** point to the same server with the same document root, you can put these rules in the htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?website.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.htm [L]
```

Comment: If I already have subdomains such as mail.mysite.com or admin.mysite.com will this script affect those?

Comment: @4cpukid Yes, this will affect all subdomains. If you want only one subdomain to do this, replace the `([^.]+)` and `%1` with the name of the subdomain. If you want all subdomains **except** mail and admin add a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mail\.mysite\.com$ [NC]` and `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.mysite\.com$ [NC]` right after the `RewriteEngine On`